# how do i display a DataTable in a wpf window c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, service, datatable

I can't seem to find a clear solution for this here or google.

i basically have a DataTable that i added rows with data according 
to my needs, and i want to display it as a table in a wpf Window.

Any ideas how?
Thanks in advance.

i tried this, but i got this exception: " **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
ListViewData was null.**"

this is the method,and inside, the creation of the DataTable:

```
private void ShowAllPlayersbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AllPlayersTable = new DataTable("test");
        AllPlayersTable.Columns.Add("Played games",typeof(int));
        AllPlayersTable.Columns.Add("Wins", typeof(int));
        AllPlayersTable.Columns.Add("Losses", typeof(int));
        AllPlayersTable.Columns.Add("Ties", typeof(int));
        AllPlayersTable.Columns.Add("Wins precentage",typeof(int));

        MsServiceClient proxy = new MsServiceClient(new InstanceContext(Callback));
        UserD[] usersArr = proxy.GetAllUsers();

        foreach(UserD uD in usersArr)
        {
            AllPlayersTable.Rows.Add(uD.PlayedGames, uD.Wins, uD.Losts, uD.Ties, uD.VictoryPercent);
        }

        DisplayUsersWindow displayWindow = new DisplayUsersWindow(AllPlayersTable);
        displayWindow.Show();

    }
```

this is the window's:

```
    public partial class DisplayUsersWindow : Window
{
    public DisplayUsersWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DataTable Datas { get; set; }
    public DisplayUsersWindow(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        Datas = dataTable;
        ListViewData.ItemsSource = Datas.DefaultView;//<<<< exception happens here

    }

}
```

}

Comment: where is the InitilaizeComponent() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullReferenceException occurs because you didn't initialize your window in the constructor that is taking the DataTable, meaning `ListViewData` is not set to an object. To fix it, just add a call to `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public DisplayUsersWindow(DataTable dataTable)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Datas = dataTable;
    ListViewData.ItemsSource = Datas.DefaultView;
}
```